# Jquery ajax load stopped working from a https site

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, cross-domain

I've got a site sitting under SSL, and it's loading data from a standard http site using jquery ajax. I control both sites and have set up a cross domain policy.

This used to work fine but has suddenly stopped for no reason.

My SSL site loads the data using:

```
$('#targetDiv').load('http://www.example.com .stuff');
```

It works under http, but not under https. In Chrome I get the following error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.secure-site-example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.example.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Now I understand it's complaining about me using http in the load() from a secure site. What I don't understand is way it's suddenly stopped working.

Has Chrome, and/or other browsers, updated their security recently? 
If so, is there a way round this problem, without having to purchase a SSL certificate for www.example.com?

Thanks.

Comment: As you can see from the error, you are being blocked by the SOP due to the protocols of the domain being different. If you've setup CORS on the domain you need to add the header manually. To do this use `$.ajax` instead of `load()` and set the relevant headers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you say, set the relevant headers, what do you mean? And is this something new that's just kicked in?

Comment: No, the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) has been around for a long time. I assumed you had already set up the domain for CORS as you stated that `both sites have setup a cross domain policy`

Comment: Yes they do. So the problem is that I'm using .load instead of .ajax. I still don't understand why it's suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Because you changed the receiving domain from `http` to `https`. If the protocols are the same on both sites, it will work fine.

Comment: But this is what I can't understand. I understand why it's complaining about the mixed protocols now, but I can't understand why it did work, even mixed protocols, and why it now doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. This looks to be a browser specific security issue. Suspect Chrome has up dated it's security setting over the past few months hence the reason the problem has occurred.

The above ajax works in Firefox if you confirm you wish to except the blocked content.

I need to find a way round ajax loading across multiple protocols. Oh well, gives me something to do I guess :)